# Apache 2.2 piping logs to program starts more than 1 process

Tags: java, apache, logging, pipe

**Background**

As a part of processing and storing the logs, it is required to store them as well as send them to kafka so as to facilitate consumption by other programs.

The setting as shown below, populates `error_log` file as well as sends to logs to  `stdout`.

Now for testing, it was tested using 2 different programs which consume logs from `stdout`, `logger` and a java producer. But few differences were observed.

**Settings as part of httpd.conf for ErrorLog**

- Java

  ```
  ErrorLog  "| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log |  java -cp producer.jar stdin.producer.StdInProducer /CustomProducer/config.json >> /producer_init.log 2>&1"`
  ```
- logger

  ```
  ErrorLog  "| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log | /usr/bin/logger -u /tmp/apache_log.socket"
  ```

When `httpd` was started, it resulted into following processes, each corresponding to respective settings given above. (pid, user, time etc details are removed to avoid cluttering)

**Processes**

- Java

  ```
  ps auxxww | grep producer
  ```

resulted in following output

```
    /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log | java -cp producer.jar stdin.producer.StdInProducer /CustomProducer/config.json >> /producer_init.log 2>&1                                                                                      
    java -cp producer.jar stdin.producer.StdInProducer /CustomProducer/config.json


    /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log | java -cp producer.jar stdin.producer.StdInProducer /CustomProducer/config.json >> /producer_init.log 2>&1                                                                                      
    java -cp producer.jar stdin.producer.StdInProducer /CustomProducer/config.json
```

- logger

  ```
  ps auxxww | grep logger
  ```

when logger related setting was used, above command gave following output

```
    /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log | /usr/bin/logger -u /tmp/apache_log.socket
    /usr/bin/logger -u /tmp/apache_log.socket
```

**Problem**

For logger I can see one process running which BTW is correct, but when I use Java setting in the conf file, it creates 2 such processes for producer. What is going on here ?

**Process count after 48 hrs of running**

`63`

It is spinning off new process every hour. The only other process happening every hour is rotation of the file `error_log`. This is done using `logrotate` and it uses `copytruncate` option. This essential keeps the file descriptor same by copying the data from file to another one and then truncating the original file.

Comment: Can somebody explain downvote reason please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic Info**

Here is how it works to start with

I referred to following links

[Error log consumption for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog)

AND

[Error Log Information](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#errorlog)

As mentioned in the question above, the requirement was to send logs to `error_log` file as well as to another program which can process them in different ways (a Apache Kafka Producer in java)

**Caveate**

The setting worked for `logger` which is a linux utility but failed to work with custom java program, reason being, when `EOF` is encountered in the data stream the consuming program should *exit*. The java producer program in this scenario had an infinite loop to consume from `stdin` continuously.
So it was modified to handle the termination when `EOF` is encountered.

As far as JAVA 1.7 is concerned it was done as

`this.stdinReader.readLine() != null`

`null` indicates EOF.